# Path Animation Evaluation Time keyframe error

Tags: animation, path

I've used Control + P ➔ Follow Path to animate an object along a path, and now I want to keyframe when the animation should start and end, but when I try to set a keyframe for the Evaluation Time value in the Curve Object Data panel, I get an error like in the screenshot.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a different way of setting the start and end frame of the Follow Path animation?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have automatically generated an animation and you need to delete if before creating any keyframe on the *Evaluation Time* value:

- Select your bezier curve.
- Open the *Graph Editor*.
- Unfold *BezierCurve* on the left to select the *Evaluation Time* track.
- Press <kbd>N</kbd> to display the *Graph Editor* properties panel on the right.
- Press the *Modifiers* tab.
- Delete the *Generator* modifier.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, Moonboots, much appreciated!